# Model Validation for Primitives in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

We have defined a Get method that accepts a long list of nullable types as parameters.  Something like:

```
[Route("api/person/get")]
public IEnumerable<Person> Get(int? age = null, string name = null, bool? isDeceased = null)
{
    ...
}
```

The idea here is that all the input parameters are nullable.  They either provide a parameter value or they don't.  If they do, we'll use it to filter their results.  This removes the need for the client to construct a JSON object and pass that in.

Question 1: Is this a good idea?

Question 2 is that we don't want them to pass 'ABC' for Age.  If they do, the Age parameter gets populated with null.  This isn't ideal.  We'd instead like to throw an appropriate exception.

If seen a lot of posts about defining a ValidateModelAttribute and decorating my web api method with that (https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/validation-response-aspnet-core-webapi/ for example).  My problem is that ModelState.IsValid is false if any of the nullable parameters are actually null.  So unless they provide an argument for every single parameter (our real method has 67 of them), ModelState.isValid will be false.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Aaron

Comment: In your Person model, you set the type of your properties and make them nullable. with the, the modelstate will be valid if the properties are of the correct type.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my first question.  What you would suggest would work if I were passing in a model object.  But I'm passing in a list of primitives.

Answer (score 0):

`ModelState` is an MVC thing, not a WebAPI thing; that's why it's always `false`.  There's nothing wrong with decorating method signature with nullable params.  If you want to create some custom errors for types I would recommend [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).  If you want to hook up `ModelState` to work in WebAPI, recommend [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that ModelState does in fact work with WebApi, but it will return false for IsValid if you have any blank input params.  So if you call

https://myApiSite/api/person/get?name=Aaron&age=

ModelState.IsValid will be false, because of the blank age parameter.

If, on the other hand, you call

https://myApiSite/api/person/get?name=Aaron

ModelState.IsValid will be true.  Age still comes in blank, as do all the other params you didn't pass, but the model will pass validation. Go figure.

Thanks.

Aaron